# Is there a way I can generate the below cross tab in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, validation, spss

[Crostab output from SPSS]
[image]

I want to generate the attached crosstab with R. Presently I used SPSS. The data frame that I used is below. variables (Maths_Set, Note_Book, School_Bag, Text_Book, Pen ) is a muliple response question in a survey, where respondent can have 1 or more of the items. if 1 is coded, it means the respondent has the item otherwise it's coded 0. The crosstab is taking Q1 as a row and Gender and the grouping of items as a column. And it generates both count and percentage in a single cell.

```
Q1 <- c(5,5,4,1,5,4,3,3,5,2)
Gender <- c(2,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,2)
Maths_Set <- c(1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1)
Note_Book <- c(1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
School_Bag <- c(0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1)
Text_Book <- c(0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
Pen <- c(0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)

df = data.frame(Q1,Gender,Maths_Set,Note_Book,School_Bag,Text_Book,Pen)
df$Q1 <- factor(df$Q1, levels= c(1,2,3,4,5), labels = c("Strongly Dislike", "Dislike", "Neither like or Dislike", "Like", "Strongly Like"))
df$Gender <- factor(df$Gender, levels = c(1,2), labels = c("Boy", "Girl"))
```

Comment: You might mean `df$Gender <- factor(df$Gender, levels = c(1,2), labels = c("Boy", "Girl"))` where you have a dangling `df$Q2 <- ...`?

Comment: Do you want pretty formatted output to put in a report, or are you just looking to get the stats presented on the screen in a format that you can interpret easily?

Comment: I will gladly appreciate if the stats can be formatted too. Thanks

Comment: @jon Spring. I have edited the Q2, it should be gender. Thanks for your observations

Comment: Not a complete answer but it looks like you can also get pretty close with `library(modelsummary); datasummary_crosstab(Q1 ~ Gender, data = df);
datasummary_crosstab(Q1 ~ name, data = df |> pivot_longer(3:7) |> filter(value >= 1))`. I'm not very familiar with the package, but there's probably a simple way to combine the two output `kableExtra` objects.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [gt](https://gt.rstudio.com/index.html) for formatting and [dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/index.html) for the aggregation:

```r
st <- df %>% 
  group_by(Q1) %>% 
  summarize(`Actual Base` = n(),
            Boy = sum(Gender == "Boy"),
            Girl = sum(Gender == "Girl"),
            across(-Gender, .fn = sum)) %>% 
  mutate(across(-Q1, .fn = list(freq = ~ .x / sum(.x))))

bt <- gt(st,
   rowname_col = "Q1") %>% 
  grand_summary_rows(fns = list("Actual Base" ~ sum(.)), 
                     side = "top") %>% 
  fmt_percent(columns = ends_with("freq"),
              decimals = 1) %>% 
  tab_spanner("Gender", c("Boy", "Girl")) %>% 
  tab_spanner("School Items", 5:9)

Reduce(\(x, y) x %>%
         cols_merge(starts_with(y), pattern = "{1} ({2})"),
       st %>% select(!ends_with("freq"), -Q1) %>% names(),
       init = bt)
```

This is just to get you started with `gt`. There are plenty of customization options and feel free to explore them to customize the table to your liking.

[image: Table produced by gt which shows counts and percentages of the table after the aggregation]

Answer (score 0):

The following creates a series of tables with the information that you are looking for, but it does not replicate the layout of the SPSS crosstab.

The advantage in this method is that the commands are straightforward.

```r
logical_vars = setdiff(names(df), c("Q1", "Gender") )
for (nn in logical_vars) {
  df[,nn] = as.logical(df[,nn])
}
mysurvey = survey::svydesign(ids = ~1, data = df)
#> Warning in svydesign.default(ids = ~1, data = df): No weights or probabilities
#> supplied, assuming equal probability
```

```r
library(surveytable)
```

```r
set_survey(mysurvey)
#> * To adjust how counts are rounded, see ?set_count_int
#>                        _                                             
#> Survey name            mysurvey                                      
#> Number of variables    7                                             
#> Number of observations 10                                            
#> Info1                  Independent Sampling design (with replacement)
#> Info2                  survey::svydesign(ids = ~1, data = df)
set_count_int()
#> * Rounding counts to the nearest integer.
#> * ?set_count_int for other options.
options(surveytable.check_present = FALSE)

tab("Q1")
tab_subset("Q1", "Gender")
for (nn in logical_vars) {
  print( tab_subset("Q1", nn, TRUE) )
}

                               Q1 {mysurvey}                                
┌────────────────┬────────┬────┬────┬───────┬─────────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ Level          │ Number │ SE │ LL │    UL │ Percent │   SE │   LL │   UL │
├────────────────┼────────┼────┼────┼───────┼─────────┼──────┼──────┼──────┤
│ Strongly       │      1 │  1 │  0 │   Inf │      10 │ 10   │  0.2 │ 47   │
│ Dislike        │        │    │    │       │         │      │      │      │
├────────────────┼────────┼────┼────┼───────┼─────────┼──────┼──────┼──────┤
│ Dislike        │      1 │  1 │  0 │   Inf │      10 │ 10   │  0.2 │ 47   │
├────────────────┼────────┼────┼────┼───────┼─────────┼──────┼──────┼──────┤
│ Neither like   │      2 │  1 │  0 │ 9,547 │      20 │ 13.3 │  2.1 │ 57.8 │
│ or Dislike     │        │    │    │       │         │      │      │      │
├────────────────┼────────┼────┼────┼───────┼─────────┼──────┼──────┼──────┤
│ Like           │      2 │  1 │  0 │ 9,547 │      20 │ 13.3 │  2.1 │ 57.8 │
├────────────────┼────────┼────┼────┼───────┼─────────┼──────┼──────┼──────┤
│ Strongly Like  │      4 │  2 │  1 │    15 │      40 │ 16.3 │ 11.1 │ 75.5 │
└────────────────┴────────┴────┴────┴───────┴─────────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘

                      Q1 (Gender = Boy) {mysurvey}                       
┌────────────────┬────────┬────┬────┬─────┬─────────┬──────┬─────┬──────┐
│ Level          │ Number │ SE │ LL │  UL │ Percent │   SE │  LL │   UL │
├────────────────┼────────┼────┼────┼─────┼─────────┼──────┼─────┼──────┤
│ Strongly       │      1 │  1 │  0 │ Inf │    33.3 │ 28.7 │ 0.6 │ 92.2 │
│ Dislike        │        │    │    │     │         │      │     │      │
├────────────────┼────────┼────┼────┼─────┼─────────┼──────┼─────┼──────┤
│ Neither like   │      1 │  1 │  0 │ Inf │    33.3 │ 28.7 │ 0.6 │ 92.2 │
│ or Dislike     │        │    │    │     │         │      │     │      │
├────────────────┼────────┼────┼────┼─────┼─────────┼──────┼─────┼──────┤
│ Strongly Like  │      1 │  1 │  0 │ Inf │    33.3 │ 28.7 │ 0.6 │ 92.2 │
└────────────────┴────────┴────┴────┴─────┴─────────┴──────┴─────┴──────┘

                       Q1 (Gender = Girl) {mysurvey}                       
┌────────────────┬────────┬────┬────┬───────┬─────────┬──────┬─────┬──────┐
│ Level          │ Number │ SE │ LL │    UL │ Percent │   SE │  LL │   UL │
├────────────────┼────────┼────┼────┼───────┼─────────┼──────┼─────┼──────┤
│ Dislike        │      1 │  1 │  0 │   Inf │    14.3 │ 13.9 │ 0.3 │ 60.6 │
├────────────────┼────────┼────┼────┼───────┼─────────┼──────┼─────┼──────┤
│ Neither like   │      1 │  1 │  0 │   Inf │    14.3 │ 13.9 │ 0.3 │ 60.6 │
│ or Dislike     │        │    │    │       │         │      │     │      │
├────────────────┼────────┼────┼────┼───────┼─────────┼──────┼─────┼──────┤
│ Like           │      2 │  1 │  0 │ 9,547 │    28.6 │ 18   │ 3.1 │ 73.2 │
├────────────────┼────────┼────┼────┼───────┼─────────┼──────┼─────┼──────┤
│ Strongly Like  │      3 │  2 │  0 │    27 │    42.9 │ 19.7 │ 8.7 │ 83.3 │
└────────────────┴────────┴────┴────┴───────┴─────────┴──────┴─────┴──────┘

                     Q1 (Maths_Set = TRUE) {mysurvey}                      
┌────────────────┬────────┬────┬────┬───────┬─────────┬──────┬─────┬──────┐
│ Level          │ Number │ SE │ LL │    UL │ Percent │   SE │  LL │   UL │
├────────────────┼────────┼────┼────┼───────┼─────────┼──────┼─────┼──────┤
│ Strongly       │      1 │  1 │  0 │   Inf │    12.5 │ 12.3 │ 0.2 │ 55.3 │
│ Dislike        │        │    │    │       │         │      │     │      │
├────────────────┼────────┼────┼────┼───────┼─────────┼──────┼─────┼──────┤
│ Dislike        │      1 │  1 │  0 │   Inf │    12.5 │ 12.3 │ 0.2 │ 55.3 │
├────────────────┼────────┼────┼────┼───────┼─────────┼──────┼─────┼──────┤
│ Neither like   │      2 │  1 │  0 │ 9,547 │    25   │ 16.1 │ 2.7 │ 67.3 │
│ or Dislike     │        │    │    │       │         │      │     │      │
├────────────────┼────────┼────┼────┼───────┼─────────┼──────┼─────┼──────┤
│ Like           │      2 │  1 │  0 │ 9,547 │    25   │ 16.1 │ 2.7 │ 67.3 │
├────────────────┼────────┼────┼────┼───────┼─────────┼──────┼─────┼──────┤
│ Strongly Like  │      2 │  1 │  0 │ 9,547 │    25   │ 16.1 │ 2.7 │ 67.3 │
└────────────────┴────────┴────┴────┴───────┴─────────┴──────┴─────┴──────┘

                      Q1 (Note_Book = TRUE) {mysurvey}                      
┌────────────────┬────────┬────┬────┬───────┬─────────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ Level          │ Number │ SE │ LL │    UL │ Percent │   SE │   LL │   UL │
├────────────────┼────────┼────┼────┼───────┼─────────┼──────┼──────┼──────┤
│ Strongly       │      1 │  1 │  0 │   Inf │    11.1 │ 11   │  0.2 │ 50.8 │
│ Dislike        │        │    │    │       │         │      │      │      │
├────────────────┼────────┼────┼────┼───────┼─────────┼──────┼──────┼──────┤
│ Dislike        │      1 │  1 │  0 │   Inf │    11.1 │ 11   │  0.2 │ 50.8 │
├────────────────┼────────┼────┼────┼───────┼─────────┼──────┼──────┼──────┤
│ Neither like   │      2 │  1 │  0 │ 9,547 │    22.2 │ 14.6 │  2.4 │ 62.2 │
│ or Dislike     │        │    │    │       │         │      │      │      │
├────────────────┼────────┼────┼────┼───────┼─────────┼──────┼──────┼──────┤
│ Like           │      1 │  1 │  0 │   Inf │    11.1 │ 11   │  0.2 │ 50.8 │
├────────────────┼────────┼────┼────┼───────┼─────────┼──────┼──────┼──────┤
│ Strongly Like  │      4 │  2 │  1 │    15 │    44.4 │ 17.5 │ 12.5 │ 80.4 │
└────────────────┴────────┴────┴────┴───────┴─────────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘

                     Q1 (School_Bag = TRUE) {mysurvey}                     
┌────────────────┬────────┬────┬────┬───────┬─────────┬──────┬─────┬──────┐
│ Level          │ Number │ SE │ LL │    UL │ Percent │   SE │  LL │   UL │
├────────────────┼────────┼────┼────┼───────┼─────────┼──────┼─────┼──────┤
│ Dislike        │      1 │  1 │  0 │   Inf │    12.5 │ 12.3 │ 0.2 │ 55.3 │
├────────────────┼────────┼────┼────┼───────┼─────────┼──────┼─────┼──────┤
│ Neither like   │      2 │  1 │  0 │ 9,547 │    25   │ 16.1 │ 2.7 │ 67.3 │
│ or Dislike     │        │    │    │       │         │      │     │      │
├────────────────┼────────┼────┼────┼───────┼─────────┼──────┼─────┼──────┤
│ Like           │      2 │  1 │  0 │ 9,547 │    25   │ 16.1 │ 2.7 │ 67.3 │
├────────────────┼────────┼────┼────┼───────┼─────────┼──────┼─────┼──────┤
│ Strongly Like  │      3 │  2 │  0 │    27 │    37.5 │ 18   │ 7.5 │ 77.4 │
└────────────────┴────────┴────┴────┴───────┴─────────┴──────┴─────┴──────┘

                     Q1 (Text_Book = TRUE) {mysurvey}                      
┌────────────────┬────────┬────┬────┬───────┬─────────┬──────┬─────┬──────┐
│ Level          │ Number │ SE │ LL │    UL │ Percent │   SE │  LL │   UL │
├────────────────┼────────┼────┼────┼───────┼─────────┼──────┼─────┼──────┤
│ Strongly       │      1 │  1 │  0 │   Inf │    12.5 │ 12.3 │ 0.2 │ 55.3 │
│ Dislike        │        │    │    │       │         │      │     │      │
├────────────────┼────────┼────┼────┼───────┼─────────┼──────┼─────┼──────┤
│ Dislike        │      1 │  1 │  0 │   Inf │    12.5 │ 12.3 │ 0.2 │ 55.3 │
├────────────────┼────────┼────┼────┼───────┼─────────┼──────┼─────┼──────┤
│ Neither like   │      2 │  1 │  0 │ 9,547 │    25   │ 16.1 │ 2.7 │ 67.3 │
│ or Dislike     │        │    │    │       │         │      │     │      │
├────────────────┼────────┼────┼────┼───────┼─────────┼──────┼─────┼──────┤
│ Like           │      1 │  1 │  0 │   Inf │    12.5 │ 12.3 │ 0.2 │ 55.3 │
├────────────────┼────────┼────┼────┼───────┼─────────┼──────┼─────┼──────┤
│ Strongly Like  │      3 │  2 │  0 │    27 │    37.5 │ 18   │ 7.5 │ 77.4 │
└────────────────┴────────┴────┴────┴───────┴─────────┴──────┴─────┴──────┘

                        Q1 (Pen = TRUE) {mysurvey}                         
┌────────────────┬────────┬────┬────┬───────┬─────────┬──────┬─────┬──────┐
│ Level          │ Number │ SE │ LL │    UL │ Percent │   SE │  LL │   UL │
├────────────────┼────────┼────┼────┼───────┼─────────┼──────┼─────┼──────┤
│ Strongly       │      1 │  1 │  0 │   Inf │    12.5 │ 12.3 │ 0.2 │ 55.3 │
│ Dislike        │        │    │    │       │         │      │     │      │
├────────────────┼────────┼────┼────┼───────┼─────────┼──────┼─────┼──────┤
│ Dislike        │      1 │  1 │  0 │   Inf │    12.5 │ 12.3 │ 0.2 │ 55.3 │
├────────────────┼────────┼────┼────┼───────┼─────────┼──────┼─────┼──────┤
│ Neither like   │      2 │  1 │  0 │ 9,547 │    25   │ 16.1 │ 2.7 │ 67.3 │
│ or Dislike     │        │    │    │       │         │      │     │      │
├────────────────┼────────┼────┼────┼───────┼─────────┼──────┼─────┼──────┤
│ Like           │      2 │  1 │  0 │ 9,547 │    25   │ 16.1 │ 2.7 │ 67.3 │
├────────────────┼────────┼────┼────┼───────┼─────────┼──────┼─────┼──────┤
│ Strongly Like  │      2 │  1 │  0 │ 9,547 │    25   │ 16.1 │ 2.7 │ 67.3 │
└────────────────┴────────┴────┴────┴───────┴─────────┴──────┴─────┴──────┘
```